# When I search my site and hit the enter key, the search performs correctly, but hitting the button, it does not

Tags: javascript, php, html

For example, if I search my site for "4486043", then hit enter, I get a search result. If I click the button next to the search bar, it searches for "Search this website...", which is the default text of the textbox.

HTML/PHP

```
function tf_common_themes_get_search()
{
  $partner_id = tf_partner_get_partner_id();
  $search_text = "Search this website...";
  $email_updates = "";
  if ("creative_habitat" == THEME_NAME)
  {
    $search_text = "search";
    $email_updates = '<div class="emailUpdates-container">
        <form id="emailUpdates" action="" method="get">
          <div class="pEmailUpdates">
            <div class="emailUpdates_background">
              <input type="text" name="search" class="emailUpdatesBox" id="emailUpdatesBox" onfocus="hidetext(this)" onblur="showtext(this)" style="color:#9F9F9F;" value="Email address"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value=" " class="emailUpdatesButton" onclick="checkfield(\'posterSearchBox\');return false;"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>';
  }
  elseif ("watertown_daily" == THEME_NAME)
  {
    $search_text = "Search this website...";
  }
  return '
    <div id="top-search">
      <div id="search-cat" style="float:left;margin:7px 0 0 15px;"></div>
      <div class="search-container">
        <form id="search" action="/commonsearch/" method="get">
          <div class="pSearch">
            <div class="search_background">
              <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="' . $partner_id . '" />
              <input type="text" name="search" class="posterSearchBox" id="posterSearchBox" onfocus="hidetext(this)" onblur="showtext(this)" style="color:#9F9F9F;" value="' . $search_text .'"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value=" " class="searchButton" onclick="checkfield(\'posterSearchBox\');return false;"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>';
}
```

Javascript:

```
var searchtext = "";
function hidetext(id){
    if(searchtext == ""){
        searchtext = id.value;
        id.value = "";
    }
}

function showtext(id){
    if(searchtext != ""){
        id.value = searchtext;
        searchtext = "";
    }
}

function checkfield(id){
    var search=null;
    if(document.getElementById(id))
        search=document.getElementById(id).value
    if (search != "" && search!=" "){
            document.search.submit();
    }

    return false
}
```

I have a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/allisonc/zY6h2/

Comment: A thing I noticed is that your standard value is inserted into the search field whenever it loses focus. No matter what you wrote into it. It seems like your hidetext() function (onfocus) will get the text back whenever the field loses focus/ you click a button or whatever. There is your problem.

Comment: I used the answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566713/search-box-text-show-hide-feature

Comment: FWIW, to be accessible for people with disabilities, all form elements need a label. The `placeholder` is not one. See http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2011/02/html5-accessibility-chops-the-placeholder-attribute/

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing strange, hitting on <kbd>enter</kbd> your textbox isn't losing focus, but clicking on search it is, and you have a mistake in your `onblur()` handler.

Anyway I can describe the situation with your code:

`onfocus="hidetext(this)"` - You're activating the focus and clearing the text, then user types, and blurs it by clicking on "search" button.

`onblur="showtext(this)"` under this event handler function you're checking  `if(searchtext != null)` , but you've gave old value to your searchtext variable in `hidetext` function, and this expression will always true.

You need to restore the value to "Search..." when user hasn't typed anything.

**So you have to check if the textbox value is null.**

```
function showtext(id){
    if(id.value.trim() == ""){ // used trim for " " cases 
        id.value = searchtext;
        searchtext = "";
    }
}
```

I've update your fiddle, please [check](http://jsfiddle.net/zY6h2/1/)

[Similar question and answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305389/password-input-field-change-from-text-to-password-on-focus-type/15305518#15305518)

**NOTE: Use HTML5 `placeholder` attribute, and everything will be clear.**
Also there is javascript lib for browsers which are doesn't support placeholders. See [Placeholder.js](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to know on your button click what is your "placeholder" text and submit only if the text is different from the placeholder